# Android. How to know permissible size of chunks (Bluetooth)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth, stream

I send data via Bluetoth to another device.

```
 val writeCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
 writeCharacteristic.value = data.toByteArray()
 val isSendSuccessful = bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(writeCharacteristic)
```

But if i trying to send too long byte array, then it don't work. So, I split it up on some chunks and send them. I need to know permissible size of chunks for current device (I think size can be different for different devices). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The default payload size is 20 byte.
On `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` you can the ask the device for it's maximum size, providing your own maximum size with 
`gatt.requestMtu(MAX_MTU)` and you get the answer in `public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status)` callback, e.g. as used [here](https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothLeTerminal/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/kai_morich/simple_bluetooth_le_terminal/SerialSocket.java#L253).